# How to see which user has created process in process builder?

Tags: flow, process-builder, process

Some one in our org has created a process, but don't know who has created it. is there any way to look who has created it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can track Process Builder creation/ updation /deletion in Audit Trails.

**Location :**

`Setup| Administer | Security Controls | View Setup Audit Trail`

You will find Process builder having section values as Flows for example:

`Date                         User            Action  Section Delegate User Help
8/18/2015 10:18:19 PM AEST  developer@capost.in Created flow version #2 "Position Update V2" for flow with Unique Name "Position_Update"    Flows

8/18/2015 10:18:19 PM AEST  developer@capost.in Deleted flow version #2 "Position Update V2" for flow with Unique Name "Position_Update"    Flows`

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if there's an easy way within Salesforce Process Builder UI to make these fields visible , but you will find this in the Metadata definition of the flows (process falls under flows).

If you use Workbench, you can select the **Metadata Types & Components** in the home page and then in the next page Select **Flow** and expand your flow to see the details.

[image]